# How to detect users with Adblock and redirect javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect, web, block, adblock

I have been searching things about how to detect an ad-block and I found some things but none of them worked. How can I detect an ad-block in my web site and redirect the users?  For example:

I have a ad-block, and go to `www.lol.com` it should redirects me to `www.lol.com/adblock.php`.

#### Edit

I just don't have ads, I'm developing a online game but users that have Adblock for some weird reason blocks the game. I just want to detect whether a user uses Adblock and tell these users to disable it.

Comment: It depends on how you produce your ads. What API do you use?

Comment: I just don't have ads, i'm developing a online game but users that have Adblock for some weird reason blocks the game. I just wan't to detect if uses Adblock and tell these users to disable it. Thanks!

Comment: What are you using to develop said game, flash?

Comment: Correct, It's a flash game.

Comment: As there are no actual advertisements in play here, it would seem a better option would be to contact Adblock and inform them of the problem. They should be able to either whitelist the game, or explain why it was blocked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If AdBlock hides your ads, you can just check if height of your ad containers is zero:

```
$(function() {
  if (!$("#yourAdContainer").height()) {
    window.location.href = "www.lol.com/adblock.php";
  }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

If you have no ads, you can create invisible block with id, known by adblock, of fixed height on page load, and check it's height. Example from my project:

```
$(document.body).append('<div id="advblock" style="position: absolute; opacity: 1; top: 0; left: 0;">hh</div>');
setTimeout(function() {
  if (!$('#advblock').height()) {
    window.location.href = "www.lol.com/adblock.php";
  }
  $("#advblock").remove();
}, 1);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GhUHD/2/)

Comment: Thanks but, I just don't have ads, i'm developing a online game but users that have Adblock for some weird reason blocks the game. I just wan't to detect if uses Adblock and tell these users to disable it. Thanks!

Comment: $('#yourAdContainer').is(':visible') also works

Comment: I don't have ads, thats the problem.

Comment: It doesn't work, ¿Why?

Comment: Check out fiddle example. Works for me in chrome and FF with adblock plus. http://jsfiddle.net/GhUHD/2/

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't show any alert. ¿It's supose to have a special configuration?

Comment: It may depend of Adblock Plus subscription. My subscription is https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/ruadlist+easylist.txt . Actually, I took `#advblock` id from that list. You may have another subscription, or maybe, you have another Adblock?

Comment: Yes thats my adblock, i will check thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if this would work now, since adblock seems to blocks all DOM ready, onload, and related functions. This is in reference to Adblock extension.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your div containing the game has a "ad like" `class` or `id` name.

Adblocks filters are big, so if you use `class` or `id` names that has

`ad` or `advertising` or something that could hint it was an ad, changes are it will get blocked because of existing filters. This has happened to me. Try renaming them.